# Push Notification for existing appid in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to `PushNotifications` . I have been facing an issue while enabling the push notification for existing `AppID` .

Long time ago I had created the Certificate, `Provisioning profile` for an app . At that time I didn't enabled the push notifications . To enable the push notifications I have logged into the `Apple Developer Account` and in the `AppIds` I have clicked the check for enabling the push notification . Then configure buttons have been enabled . If I click on the configure in the Production it is asking me to create the certificate . But I have already had a Certificate . I can't delete existing Certificate because most of my apps using the existing certificate . So please help me to enable the push notification .

1. Incase If I delete the certificate will it effect the already installed apps on the devices ?  Please let me know if my question not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending Push notifications you will have to create an SSL certificate. That is a different thing and not related to the "usual" certificates which you have to create and maintain anyway.

You will have to refresh the ssl cert. on a yearly basis. 
This certificate is not even linked to the app. It is required on the server that acutally sends the push notifications to Apple's service.

My advise: Just follow the instructions and do not get confused with any of the other certificates. And of course there is no need to delete an existing app-certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hermann . One more help is I have created the apns-dev.pem using the private key and the SSL Certificate . Is it necessary to recreate the appId and Provisioning Profile? I have followed this link http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Comment: The development and distribution certs ARE related to that app id.  Only an application with that exact bundle id (company and app id) will work with those certs.

Comment: Sorry I can't move to chat . Please tell me how find the issue . I have done all the things . In the appdelegate I have written the code for Delegates  . But I am not getting the alert atleast it is not showing the appname in the settings>Notifications. Appdelegate code is     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

Comment: The first time I was successful I was following Ray's tutorial here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: dev and dist certs are related to the app id. But they are not related to the ssl certificate. Your provisioning profile must be that of an app id which is enabled for push notifications. ... which means that you may have to crate a new one. Not sure. Hoever, Ray can explain that much better than I could. :)

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thank you I can't upvote . And I have checked your answer as correct answer . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

First of all its totally ok to revoke your development or release certificates and make new ones without affecting your apps currently released in the app store. This can be done at any time.

However for setting up push notifications you are setting up yet more certificates. These certificates dont actually get bundled with your app but are for use by your push notification system. You create a certificate for development and a certificate for release.

In the future if you need to revoke these push certificates you can do so and create new ones without affecting the app in the store. You will need to upload the new push certificates to your push notification system before you can send push notifications to your app in the store but you wont need to do a new release of the app.

Comment: Thank you jackslash . I can't upvote you . I will up vote after I reach the 15 reputations. Thank you